# Multiple Matches get worst result

Tags: excel

So I'm having trouble figuring out what I should use exactly for a report.  I know it should be a nested if, but I'm not really able to figure out how I should go about it. I need to determine if something is:

```
Delivered
Called Out
Partially Called Out
Forecasted
Partially Ordered
Not Ordered (this would simply be, if no matches, it wasn't ordered)
```

The issue is that there can be multiple orders with the same ID number (cause each ID has numerous parts). So what I need is a way to have it look at ALL the identical ID numbers and give me the WORST of the outcomes. For instance, if I had 4 identical ID's with the results:

```
Delivered
Delivered
Partially Called Out
Partially Ordered
```

The result from the formula would give me "Partially Ordered" since that is the worst outcome.

So basically, I'm looking for the worst order status result from multiple of the same ID's

I started with

```
=IF(INDEX([Report.xlsx]Report!$G:$G,MATCH(B2,[Report.xlsx]Report!$K:$K,0))=0,"Not Ordered",IF(INDEX([Report.xlsx]Report!$G:$G,MATCH(B2,[Report.xlsx]Report!$K:$K,0))="Partially Ordered","Partially Ordered",IF(INDEX([Report.xlsx]Report!$G:$G,MATCH(B2,[Report.xlsx]Report!$K:$K,0))="Forecasted","Forecasted",IF(INDEX([Report.xlsx]Report!$G:$G,MATCH(B2,[Report.xlsx]Report!$K:$K,0))="Partiially Called Out","Partially Called out",IF(INDEX([Report.xlsx]Report!$G:$G,MATCH(B2,[Report.xlsx]Report!$K:$K,0))="Called Out","Called Out",IF(INDEX([Report.xlsx]Report!$G:$G,MATCH(B2,[Report.xlsx]Report!$K:$K,0))="Delivered","Delivered"))))))
```

But this isn't getting me what I'm looking for and I'm fairly certain there's a better way...

Comment: Can you perhaps give each status a rank? I.e. "Delivered" is `1`, "Called Out" is `2`, etc. Then, if you have a match, return the `Max()` number, and use `VLOOKUP()` to see what that is?

Comment: ah, that could be done. I can add in another tab to rank each one and then put that in another column. I'll give that a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array formula like this one:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(D2,A:A,0)),INDEX(I:I,MAX(IF($A$2:$A$23=D2,IFERROR(MATCH($B$2:$B$23,I:I,0),0)))),"Not Ordered")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

This assumes that the list is in order of best to worst status.

[image]

Comment: New questions need a new post, with new examples as to what you want.